# Spin Connection, Killing Equation and Spinors under Diffeomorphism

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, spinors, differential-equations, diffeomorphism-invariance

Under a diffeomorphism $dx'^{\mu}=\frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}dx^{\nu}$ we have that the components $A_{\mu}$ of every 1-form $A=A_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$ transform as: $A'_{\mu}=\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\mu}}A_{\nu}$.

Since the spin connection $\omega^{a b}={\omega_{\mu}}^{a b}dx^{\mu}$ is a 1-form, this should also be true for its components ${\omega_{\mu}}^{a b}$.

My question is why this is not true, in the sense I will now explain:

If we take, as an example, the Minkowski space, with canonical coordinates : $ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 +dy^2+dz^2$, we obviously have that ${\omega_{\mu}}^{a b}=0$ for $\mu= t,x,y,z$, for every $a$ and $b$.

BUT if we use the spherical coordinates (which are achieved performing a diffeomorphism): $ds'^2=-dt^2+dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\varphi^2$ we have ${\omega'_{\mu}}^{a b}=0$ for $\mu= t,r$ while  ${\omega'_{\mu}}^{a b}\neq0$ $\mu= \theta, \varphi$ (for certain $a$ and $b$).

But this should be impossible if ${\omega'_{\mu}}^{a b}=\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\omega_{\nu}}^{a b}$, since as said ${\omega_{\mu}}^{a b}=0$ for every $\mu$.

This also brings another problem with spinors, that should be scalars under diffeomorphism.

If we take the Killing equations $D_\mu \epsilon=\left(\partial_\mu +\frac{1}{4} {\omega_{\mu}}^{a b}\gamma_{ab}\right)\epsilon=0$.

Then in the frame with ${\omega_{\mu}}^{a b}=0$, the Killing equations reduce to $\partial_\mu \epsilon=0$, whose obvious solution is that each component of $\epsilon$ is a generic (a priori different) constant.

But in the frame with spherical coordinates, since now ${\omega_{\theta}}^{a b}\neq0$, ${\omega_{\varphi}}^{a b}\neq0$, we have that the "constant" spinor is no more solution of the Killing equations, contrary to the assumption that spinors are invariant under diffeomorphism.

I think the answer to this problem is linked to the explicit choice of the tetrade $e^a={e^a}_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$, that is different in the two coordinates, but also in this case we should have ${e'^a}_{\mu}=\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\mu}}{e'^a}_{\nu}$, that should lead to the same conclusions.

Comment: I am assuming you mean the Levi-Civita spin connection, the one depending on the vielbein. If so, $\omega=0$ is true only up to the choice of gauge. What is true in all gauges is that the curvature is zero (flat space). You always have the freedom to Lorentz-transform your vierbein, and indeed you can go to another frame where $\omega\neq 0$. Under GCTs the spin connection does transform as a 1-form, but under LLTs it transforms inhomogeneously.